# exploding textarea values into multiple array

Tags: php

Exploding textarea value like this:

```
explode("\n", $input);
```

would result in one array.

Currently, I am storing $input in textarea like this:

```
a1
a2
a3

b1
b2
b3

c1
c2
c3
```

But I want to get multiple array which would result like this:

```
$test[0][0] = 'a1';
$test[0][1] = 'a2';
$test[0][2] = 'a3';

$test[1][0] = 'b1';
$test[1][1] = 'b2';
$test[1][2] = 'b3';

$test[2][0] = 'c1';
$test[2][1] = 'c2';
$test[2][2] = 'c3';
```

Any idea, how can I implement?

Comment: What does the `$input` look like? What format is it in?

Comment: What's the input? Based on what rule do you expect to construct that result?

Comment: In what format? is it `a1,a2,a3\nb1,b2,b3\nc1,c2,c3` for example?

Comment: With 32k reputation I'd expect you to be able to formulate better questions, and to see why this question is incomprehensible/doesn't contain all the information needed to answer it.

Comment: should be clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explode by *two newlines* to separate your groups, explode each group by a single newline:

```
$result = array_map(
    function ($group) { return explode("\n", $group); },
    explode("\n\n", $input)
);
```

Comment: amazed:) I'm getting like this: `Array ([0] => Array ([0] => a [1] => b [2] => c [3] => [4] => d [5] => e [6] => f [7] => [8] => g [9] => h [10] => i ) )`

Comment: Then your input is actually different. Are newlines `\r\n` perhaps...?

Comment: Any other idea? I would be glad if I can separate them by a group name in textarea like: `group1 a1 a2 a3 group2 b1 b2 b3 etc.` each are in new line.

Comment: Lot's of possible ways to skin this cat. `a1,a2,a3 \n b1,b2,...`, or whatever other format you can come up with. What's the easiest to ***write*** for the people needing to input this date...?!

Comment: Yeah agree. Just wanted to know using group name.

Comment: Well, yes, that's also perfectly possible if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work dont know if there is anicer way

```
$exploded_values = explode("\n", $input);

$i = 0;
$amount_of_exlodes = 0;

foreach($explodes_values as $exploded_value){
 $test[$i][] = $exploded_value;
 $amount_of_explodes ++;
 if($amount_of_explodes >= 3){
  $amount_of_explodes = 0;
  $i++;
 }

}
```

Comment: Well he wants a new array inside an array every 3 times right.. 
This might work I ahvent tested it but hey.. And it probably isnt the nicest code but it wil work.

Comment: *"he wants a new array inside an array every 3 times right"* – that's exactly what we don't know here... Could be some completely different logic.

Comment: According to his example I think thats what he wants, then this works otherwise he should make himself more clear. 

im trying to help as much people to actually get some reputation so i have more priviliges